# Trying to execute Digital Datcom using MinGW gfortran on Windows

Tags: windows, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to execute the [datcom](https://www.pdas.com/datcom.html) source code using MinGW  gfortran on Windows.

I followed the procedure of trying to compile the source code using the command:

```
gfortran  datcom.f -o datcom.exe
```

where datcom.f contains the [source code](https://www.pdas.com/datcomdownload.html).

but i'm getting a lot of errors during compilation. I have attached a snippet of a small part of the errors that were obtained during compilation if it helps. I'm pretty new to gfortran, so do understand if I've misread or missed something.

Given below are few of the compilation errors obtained, along with the relevant bits of the source file:

**Error 1**

```
Error: Rank mismatch in argument ‘mess’ at (1) (rank-1 and scalar)
datcom.f:9165:21:

 9165 |      &               4HRE  ,1,ROUTID)
```

`datcom.f` lines `9164-9165` and relevant variable declarations:

```
      SUBROUTINE EQSPCE(X,R,P,S,NP,XE,RE,PE,SE,NE,DSEDX)
!
!***  TRANSFORMS 4-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY SO THAT THE 3 INDEPENDENT ARRAYS
!     ARE EQUALLY SPACED
!
      DIMENSION ROUTID(2)
      DIMENSION CR(6),CP(6),CS(6)
      DIMENSION X(1),R(1),P(1),S(1),XE(1),RE(1),PE(1),SE(1),            &
     &          DSEDX(20)
      DIMENSION VAR(4),LGH(4)
      DATA ROUTID/4HEQSP,4HCE  /
```

```
         CALL INTERX(1,X,VAR,LGH,R,RE(I),NP,NP,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,         &
     &               4HRE  ,1,ROUTID)
```

`interx` procedure interface:

```
      SUBROUTINE INTERX (NIND,TABLE,VAR,LENGTH,DEP,ANS,LIND,LDEP,       &
     &           LX1L,LX2L,LX3L,LX4L,LX1U,LX2U,LX3U,LX4U,MESS,NMSS,ROUT)
      DIMENSION MSSCL(21),RMSCL(21)
      DIMENSION LENGTH(4),TABLE(LIND,4),DEP(LDEP),VAR(4),ROUT(2),       &
     &          MESS(20)
      EQUIVALENCE(MSSCL(1),RMSCL(1))
      DATA MSSCL  /4HINTE,4HRX  ,19*0/
      DATA SRPMSS /4H1TIN/,HOL1/4H1EXP/
```

**Error 2**

```
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘x2’ at (1); passed LOGICAL(4) to REAL(4)
datcom.f:1245:72:

 1245 |      & DATA(5),DATA(6),DATA(7),DATA(8),DATA(9),P,Q,R,S,T,NN,NM)
```

**Error 3**

```
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘kol’ (1/80) at (1)
datcom.f:40352:36:

40352 |       IF(LDM(I) .GT. 0) CALL RVALUE(KOL,L,NDML,NF,BLANK,                &
      |                                    1
```

Comment: Hi @veryreverie, it says that I cannot embed images into my post yet since i'm new here, so i've added the link for the image and i've also included the command which I used.

Comment: @veryreverie Ah gotcha, sorry about that. I have now included a few errors as text.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to your question including (hopefully) all the relevant information from `datcom.f` for the first error message.  Similar information is needed in order to answer the other error messages (although ideally these would be asked across separate stack overflow questions).

Comment: @veryreverie thanks for the help. I have edited the interx procedure interface as written above but the 1st error still persists after compilation again.

Comment: Sorry, we're miscommunicating again. I edited your question so that other people reading it would know what the problematic code was, and could hopefully offer suggestions on how to fix it. My edit doesn't solve the problem in any way.

Comment: The problem causing your first error seems to be (hat tip to francescalus) that you're passing the [Hollerith character constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollerith_constant) `4HRE` (which I believe is a very old way of writing the string `"RE  "`) to the procedure argument `mess` which as defined expects a `real` array of size `20` (because you're not using implicit none, so variables whose names start with `m` are reals by default).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem until I found the solution in the pdas website. You have to use the command.

```
gfortran  -std=legacy datcom.f -o datcom.exe
```

That should compile it with no errors, only warnings.

Here's [the info](https://www.pdas.com/datcomdownload.html).